# IF statement skipped-Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

The first IF statement is being ignored and I have no idea what could cause this. I checked the indentation and everything seems fine.As you can see in the code it prints numberRolled but when I run it it justs ignores the first IF.`

```
import random
numberRolled = random.randint(1,6)
print numberRolled
while True:
    userGuess = raw_input("Guess a number\n")
    if userGuess == numberRolled:
        print "You got it right!"
        quitYN = raw_input("Would you like to play again?\n").lower()
        if quitYN == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            break
    elif userGuess != numberRolled:
        print "Wrong!"`
```

Comment: `numberRolled` is an integer, `userGuess` is a string. `raw_input("Guess a number\n")` => `int(raw_input("Guess a number\n"))`. Also your elif is redundant! It will only get to that point if they are not equal. You can just use else.

Comment: When if statements are "ignored" that means the condition isn't true. Run the code line by line and you'd see why

Comment: Thanks Pual Rooney, that worked. =)

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` returns a **string**, but `random.randint()` returns an **int**. This means that when doing `userGuess == numberRolled` you are comparing a string to an int (which returns `False`).

To fix this simply convert one of the variables to the correct type:

```
userGuess == str(numberRolled)
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) for more information about variable types and how to compare them in python.